# parsing the month value from the yearmonth picker to month name

Tags: jquery

the following is given the month and year but I want the month not as a value but as the month name.How can I prse it to month name?

```
var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
```

this generates a value for month not the month name.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you ~

http://icodesnip.com/search/jquery%20date%20formator/